# Visual Studio 2012 open framework 3.5

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a project developed with .Net framework version 3.5
I i open in Visual Studio 2012, then it automatically upgrades to latest framework

I do NOT want this to happen, i want to work in previous version only,
Is there any setting that i need to configure

Comment: It upgraded the project file to the VS2012 format.  Not the framework target version, as long as you still have 3.5 on your machine anyway.  If you don't then you'll have to install it.

Answer (score 0):

From the project build options you can select a target framework 3.5.